# Use mock location without setting it in settings

Tags: java, android, gps, mocking, location

I am writing an App which makes use of the location mocking possibility in android.

What I would like to achive is to mock my location without setting the "allow mock locations" flag in the developer options.

I know that it is possible, because is works with this app:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lexa.fakegps&hl=en

What I tried:

Generate an apk, move it to /system/app, do a reboot
And I also tried it with and without the ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION permission in the manifest.

But it all lead to this exception:
RuntimeException: Unable to start Activity: SecurityException: Requires ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION secure setting

Comment: I'd you don't mind me asking: how does it work for you with FakeGPS? I installed the app (from store), moved the .apk (it's called base.apk)  to /system/app, and after the reboot the app works. However, i cant spoof locations while "allow mock locations" is off, and if i turn it on, then spoof using the a pp and then turn "allow mock locations" off, the spoof automatically ends. Mind sharing what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I am no longer using this app. But you might find the description in the playstore usefull: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lexa.fakegps&hl=en

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have decompiled `com.lexa.fakegps` you mentioned in question, and what it do like this:

```
private int setMockLocationSettings() {
    int value = 1;
    try {
        value = Settings.Secure.getInt(getContentResolver(),
                Settings.Secure.ALLOW_MOCK_LOCATION);
        Settings.Secure.putInt(getContentResolver(),
                Settings.Secure.ALLOW_MOCK_LOCATION, 1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return value;
}

private void restoreMockLocationSettings(int restore_value) {
    try {
        Settings.Secure.putInt(getContentResolver(),
                Settings.Secure.ALLOW_MOCK_LOCATION, restore_value);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/* every time you mock location, you should use these code */
int value = setMockLocationSettings();//toggle ALLOW_MOCK_LOCATION on
try {
    mLocationManager.setTestProviderLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, fake_location);
} catch (SecurityException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    restoreMockLocationSettings(value);//toggle ALLOW_MOCK_LOCATION off
}
```

Because the execution time of these code is very short, other apps can hardly detect the change of ALLOW_MOCK_LOCATION.

Also you need,
1. require root access to your device
2. move your app to `/system/app` or `/system/priv-app`

I tried it in my project and it works fine.

Comment: I didn't try this code in Marshmallow before, but it works for Lollipop.@Marlon

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't seem to work in marshmallow, Since google updated the system mock settings to an app picker, I cant get this to work anymore. I have decompiled com.incorporateapps.fakegps because users say that it can do this in marshmallow. The code looks the same above but it's not working for me, I don't know what i'm missing. Can you look at it? @PageNotFound

Comment: @PageNotFound: This doesn't work for me. It errors out with 'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Provider "gps" unknown' when calling setTestProviderLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER. I'm running 4.4.4.

Comment: @PageNotFound just moving the app to system/app is enough ? No need to be signed via system signature ?

Comment: @Blackkara Yes, no need to sign with system signature.

Comment: @PageNotFound I'm implemanting same code you wrote above, and moved the apk to system partition(system/app), but it says 'Permission denial: writing to secure settings requires android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS' What could be wrong with me  ?

Comment: @Blackkara add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS" />` in `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: @PageNotFound Ohh i was stuck on signing the app via system signature.. Thanks, its working now with this permission.

Answer (score 2):

You would require root access to your device to do that.

Comment: I do have root access to the device. Otherwise I couldn't have moved the apk to /system/app

Answer (score 2):

Try this http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.brandonnalls.mockmocklocations

> Some apps won't let you use them if "Allow mock locations" is turned
>   on, even if you aren't mocking your location. This helps prevent apps
>   from detecting that "Allow mock locations" is turned on.