# How to set setting secure in android Marshmallow?

Tags: android, gps, mocking, location, settings

I'm trying to copy the answer in this question:

[Use mock location without setting it in settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17412826/use-mock-location-without-setting-it-in-settings)

But on my tests it only works for Lollipop and below.

Since 6.0 Marshmallow the mock location in the settings is now an app picker. And the code:

`Settings.Secure.putInt(getContentResolver(),Settings.Secure.ALLOW_MOCK_LOCATION, 1);`

Doesn't seem to do anything anymore in marshmallow.

It is possible because there are apps that can do this like com.incorporateapps.fakegps I don't know what trick they are doing to enable this in Android 6.0. Since there are no guides or any other info about this, only the link above.