# No mock location option in developers option

Tags: android

I am using an android phone which have 4.4.4 Version of Android.I have enabled developers mode. I want to mock location for some specific purpose. But there is no option of mock location in developers option. Infect there is only one checkbox with USB Debugging Only. No other option is there. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like some manufacturers hide this option. Maybe it'll help you to set the value programatically. The property name is `Settings.Secure.ALLOW_MOCK_LOCATION`. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25849595/1101730) to see more detailed information.

Note you need root access to be able to change this settings.